# How to Filter Task from Activity Mass Delete Page

Tags: delete

In the salesforce 'mass delete records' we can delete Activities. I need to to delete `Tasks` but not `Event`. What is the filter I should use for this?

UPDATE:
I just need to know how to use 'Mass Delete Record' page to delete `Task`, other than dev console, data loader or other custom solutions

Comment: have you tried using data loader?

Comment: Data Loader or Dev console are capable of querying the object itself AFAIK. Mass delete page is not with that much our control so thinking about the proper filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Task checkbox field in your filter criteria to differentiate between Tasks and Events.

So in your case you can say **Task equals TRUE** to get all the Tasks for deletion

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can query all the tasks using developer console, and simply delete them.

```
delete [select id from Task];
```

The ids of tasks starts from 00t and for events it is 00u.
You can first query all the tasks and confirm before deleting.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm looking for how to use this mass delete page